# Updating Resultset that points to an Oracle view

Tags: oracle, view, resultset

Is it possible to do updates via Resultset to an Oracle view?  Asking as my code is giving me insufficient priviledge error when it does the rs.updateRow() call.  I have checked and I definitely have access to the table/view.

The code looks like:

```
white (rs.next()) {
  int updateStatus = getPSCforAction(status);
  rs.updateInt("SPSC", updateStatus);
  rs.updateRow;
}
```

The SELECT statement changes depends on operation but it will always be querying an Oracle view (and in some cases multiple views).  My main question is whether updating via resultSet can be done to an Oracle view (or views)?

Comment: if the view allows updates on Oracle end, should be updateable in the rs as well.

Comment: More info... what is weird is that if I modify the SELECT statement and removed a column (ROW_ID), the updateRow works.  Can't see the reason though as I need the ROW_ID.

Comment: It's because you can't update the rowid, which makes your view not updateable if you include this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question one must see a definition of you view and a SELECT statament that is used to produce the resulset in your Java code. Without looking at this it is hard to give the answer
Anyway, generar rules and limitations are described in the [Oracle Database JDBC Developer's guide:](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/resltset.htm#JJDBC28615)

> **Result Set Limitations**
>
> The following limitations are placed on queries for enhanced result
>   sets. Failure to follow these guidelines results in the JDBC driver
>   choosing an alternative result set type or concurrency type.
>
> To produce an updatable result set:
>
> - A query can select from only a single table and cannot contain any
>     join operations.
> - In addition, for inserts to be feasible, the query must select all
>     non-nullable columns and all columns that do not have a default value.
> - A query cannot use SELECT * . However, there is a workaround for this.
> - A query must select table columns only.
> - It cannot select derived columns or aggregates, such as the SUM or MAX
>     of a set of columns.
>
> To produce a scroll-sensitive result set:
>
> - A query cannot use SELECT *. However, there is a workaround for this.
> - A query can select from only a single table.
>
> Scrollable and updatable result sets cannot have any column as Stream.
>   When the server has to fetch a Stream column, it reduces the fetch
>   size to one and blocks all columns following the Stream column until
>   the Stream column is read. As a result, columns cannot be fetched in
>   bulk and scrolled through.

---

They vaguely write that:

> - A query can select from only a single **table** and cannot contain any
>     join operations.

Could be that they mean "exlusively from tables, but not views", but also they could mean: "from tables and views", nobody knows, one must test this.

---

**Another possible problem** - your view may not be updatable, that is it doesn't conform to [the following rules:](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504)

> **Notes on Updatable Views**  The following notes apply to updatable views:
>
> An updatable view is one you can use to insert, update, or delete base
>   table rows. You can create a view to be inherently updatable, or you
>   can create an INSTEAD OF trigger on any view to make it updatable.
>
> To learn whether and in what ways the columns of an inherently
>   updatable view can be modified, query the USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS data
>   dictionary view. The information displayed by this view is meaningful
>   only for inherently updatable views. For a view to be inherently
>   updatable, the following conditions must be met:
>
> - Each column in the view must map to a column of a single table. For
>     example, if a view column maps to the output of a TABLE clause (an
>     unnested collection), then the view is not inherently updatable.
>
> The view must not contain any of the following constructs:
>
> - A set operator
> - A DISTINCT operator
> - An aggregate or analytic function
> - A GROUP BY, ORDER BY, MODEL, CONNECT BY, or START WITH clause
> - A collection expression in a SELECT list
> - A subquery in a SELECT list
> - A subquery designated WITH READ ONLY Joins, with some exceptions, as
>     documented in Oracle Database Administrator's Guide
>
> In addition, if an
>   inherently updatable view contains pseudocolumns or expressions, then
>   you cannot update base table rows with an UPDATE statement that refers
>   to any of these pseudocolumns or expressions.
>
> If you want a join view to be updatable, then all of the following
>   conditions must be true:
>
> - The DML statement must affect only one table underlying the join.
> - For an INSERT statement, the view must not be created WITH CHECK
>     OPTION, and all columns into which values are inserted must come from
>     a key-preserved table. A key-preserved table is one for which every
>     primary key or unique key value in the base table is also unique in
>     the join view.
> - For an UPDATE statement, the view must not be created WITH CHECK
>     OPTION, and all columns updated must be extracted from a key-preserved
>     table.
> - For a DELETE statement, if the join results in more than one
>     key-preserved table, then Oracle Database deletes from the first table
>     named in the FROM clause, whether or not the view was created WITH
>     CHECK OPTION.

Comment: Thanks for this... yeah, I'll need to alter the code as the SQL that comes back changes depending on what the clients are trying to do.

Comment: By the way, I ended up using PreparedStatement to resolve this issue.